# Going live with a MVC site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2003

I just moved my site to my server which is windows 2003 sp2, sql 2005.

I have a mvc site running on my server (althought i have it turned off) it works fine but my new site does not work correctly

For some reason the routing fails to work on my server. I can hit the homepage fine using the domain but clicking on any link(or typing it in) results in simply a page not found issue!

"The page cannot be found
The page you are looking for might have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable."

Comment: I bet you've hardcoded those links, haven't you? Come on, don't make us guess, this is not lottery, programming is a precise science, show some real code (for example the part containing those links could be of particular interest and related to your problem).

Comment: What version of IIS is the new server?

Comment: no they was not hard coded, that would have been impressive considering im using MVC what could I have hard coded them to? 

It is IIS6 which ended up being the problem, I had forgot to set up a few things like i did for the first site!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MVC doesn't play so well with IIS6 out of the box. Have you configured a handler for either .mvc or a wildcard handler?

Comment: thanks this was the problem in the end. had to sort out the handler and also set up the wildcard dll and decheck the "check file exists"

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your MVC assemblies bin deployable: http://www.britishdeveloper.co.uk/2010/05/mvc2-deploy-could-not-load-file-or.html